# Geometry. 3d hexagonal map?

Tags: geometry

In simply words:

Square -> cube, hexagon -> ? (figure I don't know)

I want to try to create a 3d map using this figure in application by the similar way as 2d hexagonal.

Are there any such figures except of the one when a hexagonan is simply stretched along the third coordinate? I mean the following:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl0On.jpg)

Comment: This question does not belong here, at least not as it is phrased, but let me give a keyword: permutohedrons. It is a family of polyhedrons, one in each dimension, which pave the space and whose 2-dimensional representative is the regular hexagon.

Comment: If you want a polyhedron whose faces are all hexagons, sorry, can't be done. There's a formula due to Euler that rules it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what properties you are trying to emulate. However the [cuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) is a nice candidate and to some extent the octahedron and [truncated octahedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedOctahedron.html).

You can fill the plane with squares and also with equilateral triangles and with hexagons. A cube fills space very nicely and the relations to a square are obvious. There are other cell-transitive space-filling polyhedra but not anywhere near the same amount of regularity. Four are: a triangular prism, a hexagonal prism, a rhombic dodecahedron and the aforementioned truncated octahedron which is, to my eye, next nicest to a cube given that the faces are regular and symmetry high. **later** This answer turns out to be the **Bitruncated cubic honeycomb** mentioned in another answer.

Clearly a 3d triangle is a tetrahedron and in the same way that we lop off the corners of a triangle to get a hexagon, a tetrahedron yields an octahedron.

Saving best for last

- The Cuboctahedron has all vertices the same distance from the center as the common edge length, just as a hexagon does.
- The 24 edges do make 4 equatorial hexagons which is reassuring.
- The 6 vertices of a hexagon can represent the root vectors of the simple Lie Group A2 and the 12 vertices of a cuboctahedron can do the same for A3.

Answer (score 3):

The [bitruncated cubic honeycomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitruncated_cubic_honeycomb) also known as the Kelvin foam might work.